# What is a dimnames error when estimating GLS?

Tags: r, nlme

I've Googled around quite a bit and can't find documentation on this. I'm trying to estimate a feasible generalized least squares (FGLS) model on cross-sectional time series data in R. For example:

```
library(nlme)
foo <- gls(Y ~ factor(panel_ID) + X1 + X2, data = myData,
           correlation=corARMA(p=1), method='ML', na.action=na.pass)
```

When I run this (my data frame is quite large, which is why I don't include it here), I get the following error:

> Error in array(c(X, y), c(N, ncol(X) + 1), list(row.names(dataMod),
>   c(colnames(X),  :  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array
>   extent

Is anyone familiar enough with the internal workings of `gls` or the `nlme` package in general to tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Or suggest another way to go about this (I've also tried the `plm` package)?

Comment: I would try it on a subset of your data that doesn't contain `NA` values ...

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks, it's running now. Looks like it'll take a long time to converge, but at least it started.

Comment: If that turns out to work you are encouraged to post an answer to your own question, to help future readers find the answer to the problem ...

Answer (score 1):

Answer goes out to Ben Bolkner.

The main reason that in your data `NA` is presented. Please see simulation below:

```
library(nlme)

# Simulation
n <-100
myData <- data.frame(panel_ID = sample(letters[1:3], n, replace = TRUE), X1 = rnorm(n), X2 = rnorm(n), Y = rnorm(n))
# NA introduction into X1 variable in Row 10.
myData$X1[10] <- NA


foo <- gls(Y ~ factor(panel_ID) + X1 + X2, data = myData,
           correlation=corARMA(p=1), method='ML', na.action=na.pass)
```

it throws the error:

> Error in array(c(X, y), c(N, ncol(X) + 1L), list(row.names(dataMod),
>   c(colnames(X),  :  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

To eliminate the problem you can remove `NA`s then it's OK.

```
# remove NAs 
myData <- myData[!is.na(myData$X1), ]

foo <- gls(Y ~ factor(panel_ID) + X1 + X2, data = myData,
           correlation=corARMA(p=1), method='ML', na.action=na.pass)

summary(foo)
```

Output:

```
Generalized least squares fit by maximum likelihood
  Model: Y ~ factor(panel_ID) + X1 + X2 
  Data: myData 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  280.8763 299.0421 -133.4382

Correlation Structure: AR(1)
 Formula: ~1 
 Parameter estimate(s):
       Phi 
-0.3496918 

Coefficients:
                        Value  Std.Error    t-value p-value
(Intercept)        0.21510948 0.14041692  1.5319343  0.1289
factor(panel_ID)b -0.27337750 0.25997687 -1.0515455  0.2957
factor(panel_ID)c -0.21930200 0.19704831 -1.1129352  0.2686
X1                -0.00604318 0.09469452 -0.0638177  0.9493
X2                 0.23870397 0.09754513  2.4471130  0.0163

 Correlation: 
                  (Intr) fctr(pnl_ID)b fctr(pnl_ID)c X1    
factor(panel_ID)b -0.649                                   
factor(panel_ID)c -0.787  0.443                            
X1                -0.065  0.148         0.044              
X2                -0.094  0.021        -0.011         0.117

Standardized residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.07929137 -0.77670150 -0.01062337  0.52685034  2.43978797 

Residual standard error: 0.9935003 
Degrees of freedom: 99 total; 94 residual
```